# gh repo create --source not copying content of source directory while creating

Tags: git, github, github-actions

My GitHub Action is actually creating repo but not initializing git. I have the initialization done on directory level and asked GitHub CLI to use it during creation.

```
name: Create Repo
on: 
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

env:
  TEMPLATE_REPO: template # this directory and all its content will be cloned upon repo creation

jobs:
  build:
    name: Create Repo
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all
    steps:
    - name: Check out repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Create repo
      run: |
        git config --global init.defaultBranch master
        git config --global user.email "github-action@myorg.com"
        git config --global user.name "GitHub Action"
        git -C ${{ env.TEMPLATE_REPO }} init              # Initializing local directory
        gh repo create MyORG/repo-test3 --private --source=${{ env.TEMPLATE_REPO }} --remote=upstream
      env:
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}
        OWNER: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
```

The action log says `Initialized empty Git repository in /home/runner/work/wio-devops-central/wio-devops-central/template/.git/` and then its executing `gh repo create`. but Once the repo created I can see its neither initialized nor any files copied from template directory.

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankjs.